# Visibility of title text in an Admob ad?

Tags: android, admob

Google's [native ad guidelines](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6329638) don't state anything regarding the visibility of text.

I want to know if my native ad's title text will breach any rules, as it's background is an image with a black-transparent gradient.

Here is my Native Ad:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For as long as it doesn't contain any negative, violent, fraud, privacy related content that could interfere I think it shouldn't breach any rules. It will still depend on the content of your text, they check contents of your app sometimes, upon uploading in Google PlayStore.